# Color of background div not stretching when browser is resized

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create an opt-in area that stretches to hold its contents when the browser is resized (less width). I am trying to duplicate the orange picture area of this theme: http://anpsthemes.com/demo/?theme=constructo (Classic demo) where it says "FAST AND RELIABLE SERVICE FOR YOUR PROJECT..." Note that the background image doesn't stretch, but when you resize the browser it shows more of the image. This is what I would like.

I had no luck with the image, so tried background color, and the same thing happened, the background image or color doesn't "stretch" behind the content. Here is my code so far:

```
.oi {
    /*background:url(opt-bg.jpg);*/
    background-color:#f46a68;   
    width:100%;
    min-height: 100px;
}

.oi-container{          
    max-width: 1310px;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    padding-top:22px;   
}   

.left{
    max-width:670px;
    float:left;
}

.right{
    max-width:570px;
    margin-left:30px;
    float:left;
}

<div class="oi">
    <div class="oi-container">

        <div class="left">
            <div class="txt-top">GET FREE TIPS TO CREATE THE LIFE YOU LOVE</div>
            <div class="txt-bot">+ BONUS Why most health businesses fail and how to avoid it</div>
        </div>

        <div class="right">
            <form action="#" method="post" id="oi">
                <input type="text" class="input" value="first name" />
                <input type="text" class="input" value="email address" />
                <input type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('oi').submit();" value"get it" class="btn-get-it" />
            </form>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

I did inspect the theme's code, but can't really duplicate it, I'm not good with position divs within each other. You can see the code live here: http://itlive.ca/oi

Any help or a point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which background isn't 'stretching' for you?  Appears to work fine in Chrome (if it's `.oi`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.left` and `.right` are floated, and therefore the containing elements, `.oi` for example, won't contain them, which is why they spill over when the window is resized.

Clearing those floats somehow (adding another element below and applying the `clear` CSS property, or using the  [clearfix](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/) method) might be a solution.

Comment: Thanks! Wow. I added <div style="clear:both;"></div> below the left and right div's and now it is working exactly as intended. It's funny, I had the clear code in before, but removed in when I made additional changes. Thanks again :)

Comment: If you want to have a look at how the clearfix works with it you can check it out here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ln0j07q6/)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to show this to me. Very helpful :)